# Using Git-GUI and Git-Bash on windows: location of *.git file?

Tags: git, git-gui

I'm new to Git, and I used a command like this to clone a git repo onto my computer:

```
git clone git://git.domain.com/dir1/dir2/myrepo.git
```

I'm also trying to experiment with the Git-GUI on windows.  It asks for the location of a repo file:
[image]

I have no idea what to put here.  I tried putting `git://git.domain.com/dir1/dir2/myrepo.git`, but it says "not a Git repository".  I can't find any *.git file on my hard drive where the clone operation put things.  If it makes any difference, the repo is actually empty.

Any ideas on how to populate this field?  Thanks.  Sorry for the 'dumb' question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just navigate to the folder you cloned it to.

The git files are stored in a folder called `.git`, and that's located in the place you cloned to. Just select the *folder* you cloned to and you're set to go.

Comment: @Adam: To 'navigate' use the 'Browse' button at the right-hand end of the repository name line. Obvious if you've seen it, easy to miss if under your nose ;-) [been there]. Once you have done it once the recently opened repos are listed for immediate clicking.